# how do you query to show the number of clients who are not assigned to any item

Tags: sql

I have a table which shows all my registered customers.
and I have a table which shows all customers that made a request.
How do i write a query to show the number of customers that did not make a request?

below is what i tried

```
SELECT a.Client_ID, 
       b.Client_ID, 
       COUNT(a.Client_ID) As NumberOfClients
FROM Client as a
FULL OUTER JOIN InPayment as b 
ON a.Client_ID = b.Client_ID
WHERE b.Client_ID is null
GROUP BY a.Client_ID,b.Client_ID;
```

unfortunately my count code does not return the value of customers that did not make a request. please help.

```
Client_ID Client_ID NumberOfClients
4         NULL       1
5         NULL       1
6         NULL       1
8         NULL       1
10        NULL       1
11        NULL       1
12        NULL       1
13        NULL       1
14        NULL       1
15        NULL       1
```

The answer should be just 10 not a new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following gets the clients with no requests:

```
select c.*
from clients c
where not exists (select 1 from inpayment i where i.client_id = c.client_id);
```

Just use `count(*)` to get the number:

```
select count(*)
from clients c
where not exists (select 1 from inpayment i where i.client_id = c.client_id);
```

Comment: Wow count(*) works just perfectly...thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

There are *couple* of ways are available for that

Use of `joins`

```
select c.*  -- use count(*) to get the NumberOfClients instead of c.*
from clients c left join inpayment p 
               on p.client_id = c.client_id 
where p.client_id is null;
```

Use of `not exists`

```
select * from clients c -- use count(*) to get the NumberOfClients 
where not exists (select 1 from inpayment where client_id = c.client_id);
```